# scala process with spaces not working correctly

Tags: shell, scala, process, pipe, spaces

I have a scala process command like below to use linux bash egrep command. But the search results are not the same in terminal and in my scala generated file. Scala results contain everything that has "new" and "Exception" while I want the output to contains only lines having "new Exception". Am I missing something here? Please help

```
    if (("egrep -r -I -n -E \"*new Exception*\" /mysource/" #| 
            "grep -v .svn").! == 0) {
        out.println(("egrep -r -I -n -E \"*new Exception*\" /mysource/" #| 
            "grep -v .svn").!!)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) say (under "What to Run and How"): `Implicitly, each process is created either out of a String, with arguments separated by spaces -- no escaping of spaces is possible -- or out of a scala.collection.Seq, where the first element represents the command name, and the remaining elements are arguments to it. In this latter case, arguments may contain spaces`

So, apparently if you need to pass the command line a single argument with spaces, like `new Exception`, you need to create the process builder from a `Seq` instead of a single `String`.